# Red Hat 6.5 - Login Errors After Security Hardening

Tags: security, redhat, login, pam

I followed the information below, however, it is strangely blocking me from entering a password upon entering the login prompt on the server:

To configure the system to lock out accounts after a number of incorrect login attempts and require an administrator to unlock the account using pam_faillock.so:

Add the following lines immediately below the pam_env.so statement in /etc/pam.d/system-auth:

> auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail deny=3 unlock_time=604800
>   fail_interval=900
>
> auth required pam_faillock.so authsucc deny=3 unlock_time=604800
>   fail_interval=900

Locking out user accounts after a number of incorrect attempts prevents direct password guessing attacks. Ensuring that an administrator is involved in unlocking locked accounts draws appropriate attention to such situations.

**I should mention this is part of a post script on a kickstart disc, but that shouldn't cause any errors... Any thoughts? The exact line I am using is:**

> sed -i "/pam_fprintd.so/ i auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail
>   deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900\nauth required
>   pam_faillock.so authsucc deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900"
>   /etc/pam.d/system-auth

Comment: Did you find this tutorial on the Internet somewhere?

Comment: This is the recommended remedy provided by a security scan I performed (with openscap).

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The DISA STIGs for RHEL 6 is a poor resource.   Instead, consider the CIS RHEL 6 Security Guide.

This will even work for Winbind Active Directory Accounts and local root login. Then put your name and STIG ID if it helps you remember for future changes.

```
//# Modified By Jordi Rubalcaba STIG ID:    RHEL-06-000357
auth    required      pam_faillock.so preauth silent deny=3 even_deny_root unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900
auth    [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail deny=3 even_deny_root unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900
//# Modified By Jordi Rubalcaba

//# Modified By Jordi Rubalcaba
account      required pam_faillock.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have to do is flip the order. The `[default=die]` is causing all your attempts to count as *bad* attempts. The guide I am following has the `[default=die]` second. I can log on with local accounts; my issue is logging on with Active Directory accounts with these lines enabled. I comment them out and it all works fine.